A keyvault created with access policy using BICEP creates compound identity
I'm creating infrastructure in Azure using BICEP for our enterprise application. Our application uses key vaults to store and recall secrets using a service principal (application).
When I create the KV in BICEP and associate the service principal with it, it is created as a compound identity in the KV access policies. I need it to added as a 'application', which is what happens when I add it manually via the Azure Portal.
How can I add my service principal as an application and not a compound identity?
resource accessPolicydev 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies@2023-07-01' = {
  parent: keyvaultExisting
  name: 'add'
  properties: {
    accessPolicies: [
      {
        tenantId: tenantId
        objectId: objectId
        applicationId: applicationId
        permissions: {
          secrets: [
            'all'
          ]
          certificates: [
            'all'
          ]
          keys: [
            'all'
          ]
        }        
      }    
    ]
  }
}



you just need to specify the objectid of the related service principal. remove the applicationId property

as per documentation, applicationid is for on behalf flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/accesspolicies?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#accesspolicyentry. it is not the app id of your service principal

remove applicationId

@Thomas, if I remove the application ID, the service principal isn't added at all.

it has to be the objectid of the service principal, not the object id of the app registration

ApplicationId should be specified for on-behalf flow as per documentation so you shouldn't specify it in the access policy.
Also the objectid should be the objectid of the service principal not the objectid of the app registration.
this should work:
provider microsoftGraph

param applicationId string  
param keyVaulName string
param tenantId string = subscription().tenantId

// Reference to the service principal
resource servicePrincipal 'Microsoft.Graph/servicePrincipals@v1.0' existing = {
  appId: applicationId
}

// Reference to key vault
resource keyVault 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-02-01' existing = {
  name: keyVaulName
}

// Create access policy
resource accessPolicy 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies@2023-07-01' = {
  parent: keyVault
  name: 'add'
  properties: {
    accessPolicies: [
      {
        tenantId: tenantId
        objectId: servicePrincipal.id
        permissions: {
          secrets: [
            'all'
          ]
          certificates: [
            'all'
          ]
          keys: [
            'all'
          ]
        }        
      }    
    ]
  }
}


You were correct, I was adding the wrong object ID.

Good to hear it is working for you
